# EC2: Failed to connect to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, minecraft

I have set up an EC2 instance to run a server which was working properly for about 20 minutes. Users were able to connect and interact through the server, and the EC2 server logs were logging life-cycle events etc. Then all of a sudden the below error was given:

[image]

I cannot find any support for this error. I am running a t2.medium EC2 server.

Comment: can you check your security groups? and can you also check whether youserver is running or not?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error in a Minecraft client saying that it was unable to reach that instance on the given port. You would need to **examine the software (presumably a Minecraft server) running on that instance** to determine what is happening.

You can also **look at metrics in Amazon CloudWatch**. It can only show information by looking at the instance 'from the outside', such as CPU Utilization and Network packets.

Please note that the **T2 family of instances** are [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html), meaning that they can provide lots of CPU for a certain amount of time, but will be limited if they exceed a given allocation of 'CPU credits'. These instances are great for workloads that are spiky, but not great for continuous workloads. So, it might be that the credits were consumed and the software is now slowing down too much for the users to be able to interact.